# how to convert my code into a tab using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

i have been solving the problem and couldn't make it to work the way i want, i'm totally new to tkinter and im trying to solve whatever i can while coding this whole thing on my own. the problem here is when i tried using ttk.notebook into my current code which is the main window to calculate, i would like to create a tab for each calculator for my own mini projects.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import math as mt

class truepositioncal:
  def __init__(self):
    
    #create main window
    self.main_window = tk.Tk()
    
    #Main Window Title
    self.main_window.title('True Position Calculator')

    #main window size
    self.main_window.geometry('400x300')
    
    #tabs widgets
    self.tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self.main_window)
    self.tab_control2 = ttk.Notebook(self.main_window)

    #Create Frame
    self.maxtrueposition_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.nom_x_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.nom_y_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.act_x_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.act_y_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.nom_dia_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.tol_pos_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.tol_neg_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.act_dia_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.result_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.calculate_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.mmc_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.lmc_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab_control)

    #adding tabs
    self.tab_control.add(self.maxtrueposition_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.nom_x_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.nom_y_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.act_x_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.act_y_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.nom_dia_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.tol_pos_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.tol_neg_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.act_dia_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.result_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.calculate_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.mmc_frame, text ='Tab-0')
    self.tab_control.add(self.lmc_frame, text ='Tab-0')


    
    self.tab_control.pack(fill= tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    self.tab_control2.pack(fill= tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    #prompt label Max True position
    self.promptlabelmaxpos = tk.Label(self.maxtrueposition_frame, text = 'Max Position Deviation:')
    #Input Max True Position
    self.maxposdev = tk.Entry(self.maxtrueposition_frame, width = 10)
    self.promptlabelmaxpos.pack(side = 'left')
    self.maxposdev.pack(side = 'left')

    #Prompt label nominal X 
    self.labeldrawingpara_x = tk.Label(self.nom_x_frame, text = 'Nominal X Value:')
    self.nominal_x = tk.Entry(self.nom_x_frame, width=10)

    #pack to left (nominal X)
    self.labeldrawingpara_x.pack(side = 'left')
    self.nominal_x.pack(side = 'left')

    #Prompt label nominal y 
    self.labeldrawingpara_y = tk.Label(self.nom_y_frame, text = 'Nominal Y Value:')
    self.nominal_y = tk.Entry(self.nom_y_frame, width=10)
    self.labeldrawingpara_y.pack(side = 'left')
    self.nominal_y.pack(side = 'left')

    #Prompt label actual X 
    self.labelact_x = tk.Label(self.act_x_frame, text = 'Actual X Value:')
    self.act_x = tk.Entry(self.act_x_frame, width=10)
    self.labelact_x.pack(side = 'left')
    self.act_x.pack(side = 'left')

    #Prompt label Actual Y 
    self.labelact_y = tk.Label(self.act_y_frame, text = 'Actual Y Value:')
    self.act_y = tk.Entry(self.act_y_frame, width=10)
    self.labelact_y.pack(side = 'left')
    self.act_y.pack(side = 'left')

    #Prompt label Nominal Diameter 
    self.labelnomdia = tk.Label(self.nom_dia_frame, text = 'Nominal Diameter Value:')
    self.nom_dia = tk.Entry(self.nom_dia_frame, width=10)
    self.labelnomdia.pack(side = 'left')
    self.nom_dia.pack(side = 'left')  

    #Prompt label tolerance positive 
    self.labeltolpos = tk.Label(self.tol_pos_frame, text = 'Tolerance (+) Value:')
    self.tol_pos = tk.Entry(self.tol_pos_frame, width=10)
    self.labeltolpos.pack(side = 'left')
    self.tol_pos.pack(side = 'left')  

    #Prompt label tolerance Negative 
    self.labeltolneg = tk.Label(self.tol_neg_frame, text = 'Tolerance (-) Value:')
    self.tol_neg = tk.Entry(self.tol_neg_frame, width=10)
    self.labeltolneg.pack(side = 'left')
    self.tol_neg.pack(side = 'left')

    #Prompt Label for Actual Diameter
    self.labelactdia = tk.Label(self.act_dia_frame, text = 'Actual Diameter:')
    self.act_dia = tk.Entry(self.act_dia_frame, width=10)
    self.labelactdia.pack(side = 'left')
    self.act_dia.pack(side = 'left')
    
    #Create and pack the widgets for the true position results 
    self.result_label = tk.Label(self.result_frame,text='Actual Position Result:')

    self.rs = tk.StringVar()
    self.rs_label = tk.Label(self.result_frame,
textvariable=self.rs)

    self.result_label.pack(side='left') 
    self.rs_label.pack(side='left')

    self.calc_button = tk.Button(self.calculate_frame, text='Calculate',
command=self.caltruepos)

    self.calc_button.pack(side='left')

    #create widgets for MMC results
    self.mmc_result_label = tk.Label(self.mmc_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (MMC):')

    self.mmc = tk.StringVar()
    self.mmc_label = tk.Label(self.mmc_frame, textvariable=self.mmc)

    self.mmc_result_label.pack(side='left')
    self.mmc_label.pack(side='left')

    #create widgets for lmc results
    self.lmc_result_label = tk.Label(self.lmc_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (LMC):')

    self.lmc = tk.StringVar()
    self.lmc_label = tk.Label(self.lmc_frame, textvariable=self.lmc)

    self.lmc_result_label.pack(side='left')
    self.lmc_label.pack(side='left')

    #Pack into one
    self.maxtrueposition_frame.pack()
    self.nom_x_frame.pack()
    self.nom_y_frame.pack()
    self.act_x_frame.pack()
    self.act_y_frame.pack()
    self.nom_dia_frame.pack()
    self.tol_pos_frame.pack()
    self.tol_neg_frame.pack()
    self.act_dia_frame.pack()
    self.result_frame.pack()
    self.mmc_frame.pack()
    self.lmc_frame.pack()
    self.calculate_frame.pack()
  
    tk.mainloop()

  def caltruepos(self):
  
    #Change string into float numbers
    maxtrueposition = float(self.maxposdev.get())
    nom_x_a = float(self.nominal_x.get())
    nom_y_a = float(self.nominal_y.get())
    act_x_a = float(self.act_x.get())
    act_y_a = float(self.act_y.get())
    nom_dia_a = float(self.nom_dia.get())
    tol_pos_a = float(self.tol_pos.get())
    tol_neg_a = float(self.tol_neg.get()) 
    act_dia_a = float(self.act_dia.get())
  
    #calculate true position
    x = nom_x_a - act_x_a
    y = nom_y_a - act_y_a
    square_Root = mt.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y))
    Value = 2 * square_Root
  
    #calculate true position mmc
    a_mmc = act_dia_a - (nom_dia_a - tol_neg_a) + maxtrueposition

    #calculate true position lmc
    a_lmc = (nom_dia_a + tol_pos_a) - act_dia_a + maxtrueposition

    #showing pass or fail
    if Value <= maxtrueposition:
      self.rs_label["background"] = "green"
    else:
      self.rs_label["background"] = "red"
    if Value <= a_mmc:
      self.mmc_label["background"] = "green"
    else:
      self.mmc_label["background"] = "red"
    if Value <= a_lmc:
      self.lmc_label["background"] = "green"
    else:
      self.lmc_label["background"] = "red"
    
    #roundup to 3 decimal places
    true_position_result = '{:.3f}'.format(Value)
    mmc_result = '{:.3f}'.format(a_mmc)
    lmc_result = '{:.3f}'.format(a_lmc)

    #float to StringVar
    self.rs.set(true_position_result)
    self.mmc.set(mmc_result)
    self.lmc.set(lmc_result)

trueposcal_a = truepositioncal()
```

Answer (score 2):

A notebook allows you to add frames to it as tabs, so if you make your "calculator" into a frame, you can simply add it to the notebook at a certain tab.

note that it's generally recommended to only control children one level deeper than your current frame, and you are controlling children two levels deep in your `truepositioncal` which is not recommended and makes your code harder to read.

changing your calculator into a frame is the recommended way and manually adding it to the main window notebook is as follows.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import math as mt


class truepositioncal(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master=master)

        # Create Frame
        self.maxtrueposition_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_x_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_y_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_x_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_y_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_dia_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tol_pos_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tol_neg_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_dia_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.result_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.calculate_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mmc_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.lmc_frame = tk.Frame(self)

        # prompt label Max True position
        self.promptlabelmaxpos = tk.Label(self.maxtrueposition_frame, text='Max Position Deviation:')
        # Input Max True Position
        self.maxposdev = tk.Entry(self.maxtrueposition_frame, width=10)
        self.promptlabelmaxpos.pack(side='left')
        self.maxposdev.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label nominal X
        self.labeldrawingpara_x = tk.Label(self.nom_x_frame, text='Nominal X Value:')
        self.nominal_x = tk.Entry(self.nom_x_frame, width=10)

        # pack to left (nominal X)
        self.labeldrawingpara_x.pack(side='left')
        self.nominal_x.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label nominal y
        self.labeldrawingpara_y = tk.Label(self.nom_y_frame, text='Nominal Y Value:')
        self.nominal_y = tk.Entry(self.nom_y_frame, width=10)
        self.labeldrawingpara_y.pack(side='left')
        self.nominal_y.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label actual X
        self.labelact_x = tk.Label(self.act_x_frame, text='Actual X Value:')
        self.act_x = tk.Entry(self.act_x_frame, width=10)
        self.labelact_x.pack(side='left')
        self.act_x.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label Actual Y
        self.labelact_y = tk.Label(self.act_y_frame, text='Actual Y Value:')
        self.act_y = tk.Entry(self.act_y_frame, width=10)
        self.labelact_y.pack(side='left')
        self.act_y.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label Nominal Diameter
        self.labelnomdia = tk.Label(self.nom_dia_frame, text='Nominal Diameter Value:')
        self.nom_dia = tk.Entry(self.nom_dia_frame, width=10)
        self.labelnomdia.pack(side='left')
        self.nom_dia.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label tolerance positive
        self.labeltolpos = tk.Label(self.tol_pos_frame, text='Tolerance (+) Value:')
        self.tol_pos = tk.Entry(self.tol_pos_frame, width=10)
        self.labeltolpos.pack(side='left')
        self.tol_pos.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label tolerance Negative
        self.labeltolneg = tk.Label(self.tol_neg_frame, text='Tolerance (-) Value:')
        self.tol_neg = tk.Entry(self.tol_neg_frame, width=10)
        self.labeltolneg.pack(side='left')
        self.tol_neg.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt Label for Actual Diameter
        self.labelactdia = tk.Label(self.act_dia_frame, text='Actual Diameter:')
        self.act_dia = tk.Entry(self.act_dia_frame, width=10)
        self.labelactdia.pack(side='left')
        self.act_dia.pack(side='left')

        # Create and pack the widgets for the true position results
        self.result_label = tk.Label(self.result_frame, text='Actual Position Result:')

        self.rs = tk.StringVar()
        self.rs_label = tk.Label(self.result_frame,
                                 textvariable=self.rs)

        self.result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.rs_label.pack(side='left')

        self.calc_button = tk.Button(self.calculate_frame, text='Calculate',
                                     command=self.caltruepos)

        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')

        # create widgets for MMC results
        self.mmc_result_label = tk.Label(self.mmc_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (MMC):')

        self.mmc = tk.StringVar()
        self.mmc_label = tk.Label(self.mmc_frame, textvariable=self.mmc)

        self.mmc_result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.mmc_label.pack(side='left')

        # create widgets for lmc results
        self.lmc_result_label = tk.Label(self.lmc_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (LMC):')

        self.lmc = tk.StringVar()
        self.lmc_label = tk.Label(self.lmc_frame, textvariable=self.lmc)

        self.lmc_result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.lmc_label.pack(side='left')

        # Pack into one
        self.maxtrueposition_frame.pack()
        self.nom_x_frame.pack()
        self.nom_y_frame.pack()
        self.act_x_frame.pack()
        self.act_y_frame.pack()
        self.nom_dia_frame.pack()
        self.tol_pos_frame.pack()
        self.tol_neg_frame.pack()
        self.act_dia_frame.pack()
        self.result_frame.pack()
        self.mmc_frame.pack()
        self.lmc_frame.pack()
        self.calculate_frame.pack()

    def caltruepos(self):
        ...  # add your logic here


main_window = tk.Tk()
# Main Window Title
main_window.title('True Position Calculator')

# main window size
main_window.geometry('400x600')

# tab notebook
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(main_window)
tab_control.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# tabs widgets
trueposcal_a = truepositioncal(tab_control)
tab_control.add(trueposcal_a, text='Tab-0')
trueposcal_b = truepositioncal(tab_control)
tab_control.add(trueposcal_b, text='Tab-1')

# tab notebook 2
tab_control2 = ttk.Notebook(main_window)
tab_control2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# tabs widgets 2
trueposcal_a2 = truepositioncal(tab_control2)
tab_control2.add(trueposcal_a2, text='Tab-0')
trueposcal_b2 = truepositioncal(tab_control2)
tab_control2.add(trueposcal_b2, text='Tab-1')

tk.mainloop()
```

if you want the extra logic to be contained in a class then you should contain it in another class (call it MainWindow), but don't put that logic inside you calculator, so your calculator stays an independent reusable frame, that you can add/reuse anywhere.

Comment: if for example, if i want to create a 2nd tabs and redo the same calculator on 2nd tab, do i need to create a new file or can i put it together?

Comment: @noel what do you mean by 2nd tabs, do you mean like below or next to your current tabs, or like 3 tabs instead of 2 ? if you want to add more "notebooks" to your main window then you can simply do that by repeating the last 6 lines with different names (before mainloop).

Comment: @noel i just modified the above example to create another notebook below the first one, by simply repeating the last 6 lines with different names.

Comment: i mean like if i got a tab 2 and i want to use tab 2 to create another new calculator to calculate another thing, can i do that?

Comment: for example i want use this code to create another new calculation on another math 
trueposcal_b2 = truepositioncal(tab_control2)
tab_control2.add(trueposcal_b2, text='Tab-1')

Comment: as in i want tab-0 to be standalone and tab-1 to be another new calculator standalone on each tabs

Comment: @noel yes, just create another calculator class like the first one and add it to the notebook the same way the first one was added, being contained in a frame makes it isolated and easy to add/remove.

Comment: if i create another calculator class, do i need to add a new window like tk.Tk(), because im thinking i have a window and if i create another one then i should remove the tk.Tk()

Comment: @noel you just repeat the two lines `my_new_tab_instance = my_new_tab_class(tab_control); tab_control.add(my_new_tab_instance , text='Tab-1')`, don't create or mess with anything else in the program, you don't need to create a new window.

Comment: so after this code it will be the new class and will repeat again
" # tabs widgets 2
trueposcal_a2 = truepositioncal(tab_control2)
tab_control2.add(trueposcal_a2, text='Tab-0')"

Comment: @noel yes, with your new class name, and a different tab text/name.